# Highscore still not saving to Shared Preferences

Tags: java, android

I am trying to save a simple Highscore to my game, but the data isn't saving to shared preferences.

SharedPrefManager.java:

```
package com.divergent.thumbler;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

// all methods are static , so we can call from any where in the code
//all member variables are private, so that we can save load with our own fun only
public class SharedPrefManager {
//this is your shared preference file name, in which we will save data
public static final String MY_EMP_PREFS = "MySharedPref";  

//saving the context, so that we can call all 
//shared pref methods from non activity classes. 
//because getSharedPreferences required the context.
//but in activity class we can call without this context
private static Context     mContext; 

// will get user input in below variables, then will store in to shared pref
private static int         HighScore;

public static void Init(Context context)
{
    mContext = context;
}
public static void LoadFromPref()
{
    SharedPreferences settings     = mContext.getSharedPreferences(MY_EMP_PREFS, 0);
    // Note here the 2nd parameter 0 is the default parameter for private access,
    //Operating mode. Use 0 or MODE_PRIVATE for the default operation,
    settings.getInt("HighScore", HighScore);

}
public static void StoreToPref()
{
    // get the existing preference file
    SharedPreferences settings = mContext.getSharedPreferences(MY_EMP_PREFS, 0); 
    //need an editor to edit and save values
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

    editor.putInt("HighScore", HighScore);

    //final step to commit (save)the changes in to the shared pref
    editor.commit(); 
}

public static void DeleteSingleEntryFromPref(String keyName)
{
    SharedPreferences settings = mContext.getSharedPreferences(MY_EMP_PREFS, 0); 
    //need an editor to edit and save values
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.remove(keyName);
    editor.commit();
}

public static void DeleteAllEntriesFromPref()
{
    SharedPreferences settings = mContext.getSharedPreferences(MY_EMP_PREFS, 0); 
    //need an editor to edit and save values
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
}


public static void SetHighScore(int score)
{
    HighScore = score;

}

public static int getHighScore()
{
    return HighScore ;
}
}
```

I am saving my highscore with the following function:

```
public void highscoreSaver() {
    SharedPrefManager.LoadFromPref();
    if(finalScore > SharedPrefManager.getHighScore()) {
        SharedPrefManager.SetHighScore(finalScore);             
        SharedPrefManager.StoreToPref();
        }

}
```

And getting my highscore like this:

```
HighScore = SharedPrefManager.getHighScore();
```

Is there anything that im doing wrong? Please let me know

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in `settings.getInt("HighScore", HighScore);`
As per documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29), `SharedPreferences.getInt(String, int)` returns an integer, the second parameter is for giving default value if there is no preference with the given key so you should do something like `HighScore = settings.getInt("HighScore", 0);` instead

Comment: I tried setting it to 0, but it didnt work

Comment: What do you mean setting it to 0?

Comment: "settings.getInt("HighScore", 0);" You told me to try that, it didnt fix the problem

Comment: You didn't forget to assign it to `HighScore` right?

Comment: Meaning what? Where do I assign it to HighScore

Comment: `HighScore = settings.getInt("HighScore", 0)`

Comment: Yes I have done that. That does not seem to be the issue. I really need this fixed